# Returning two property values concatenated as one item

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm not sure if this can be done. I'm just learning how NSFetchedResultsController and Predicates work.

I have a person entity, where two properties are first name and last name. I want them to appear concatenated together in one cell, either as " " or ", , depending on the user's preference.

In order to use the NSFetchedResultsController for managing my UITableView cells, is there a way to write the fetch request so that the two fields are handled as a combination within the NSFetchedResultsController?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of Core Data as SQL. The values are not in fields, they are attributes of objects. The fetched results controller returns an array of objects, each of which (presumably) has a `firstName` and `lastName` attribute.

To make the concatenated values appear in the UI, you would simply create a concatenated string in the UITableviewDataSource object that provides the tableviews data. Usually, these days you do it in method called something like 'cellForRow:`.

```
NSManagedObject *mo=[[fetcheResultsController fetchObjects] objectAtIndex:index.row];
NSString *fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[mo valueForKey:@"firstName"],[mo valueForKey:@"lastName"]];
cell.nameLabel.text=fullName;
```